# Adding control characters to string constants in ca65 assembler

Tags: commodore-64, assembly, cc65

According to the [cc65 documentation](https://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html), a string constant in assembler programs can be defined with the `.ASCIIZ` command. However, I could not manage to sneak control commands in, for example, the backslash character is transcribed literally into character `0xBF`. Given that commodore systems provide a powerful set of control characters including color setting this would be useful. Is there an escape character in `ca65` to add such commands to a text string?

Example:

```
msg .ASCIIZ "hello world"
```

How could I add, for example, a control character for changing to white color before the second word? The CBM code for white is `05`.

Comment: For code that specifically targets C64, you may want to look at 64tass (http://tass64.sourceforge.net/). You can write things like `.text "{clr}Text in PETSCII\n"`.

Comment: Is there some reason you want to avoid writing the screen directly?  Performance is much better than using the Kernel routine.

Comment: @supercat: Using a routine that writes to the screen directly is fast, but at the cost of having exactly these control commands I'm interested in using.

Comment: @PeterB.: What are you seeking to do with the control characters that could not be done just as well by writing display memory yourself?

Comment: There are multiple applications. For example, I have made a driver that maps every character printing either to screen memory or to graphics memory. So the same program if just using printf-commands will run in the normal mode as well as in hires graphics mode. I never understood btw why they did not introduce this feature on the C128 BASIC. There is a seperate command for printing to screen, although it could have been mapped to the standard output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there an escape character in ca65 to add such commands to a text string?

In general: No.

The whole ASCII(Z) mechanic is meant to write device independent code, so adding device specific sequences is rather outside of the scope. To get arbitrary inserts, you may want to use the good old `.BYTE`:

```
msg  .BYTE "Hello ",$05,"World",0
```

---

Then again, **there is a way** to do it, it just comes with a big caveat.

Starting with version 2.18 (*1,2) escape code processing can be enabled via a [feature](https://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html#ss11.43) (*3)

```
.FEATURE STRING_ESCAPES
```

This will enable C-style escape codes for special characters. Now it's possible to write

```
msg   .ASCIIZ "Hello \x05World"
```

So far a great thing, except, this is only painless on the source/module side, as **character mapping according to the target** will kick in when linking (*4). When linking, strings get translated into target codes, which can be vastly different depending on each machine.

---

**Now, since we already left the path of compatibility**, there is a way to add (somewhat) machine independent support by using defined character codes and have their mapping fixed using the `.CHARMAP` directive. And with a bit of Macro-Fu logical names could be used as well ... but all of that is a complete different story :)

---

*1 - More correct, it wasn't there in 2.15, but is available in 2.18.

*2 - It also seems to be a backport by Oliver Schmidt from 2.5 into the free version.

*3 - When using the command line option, feature needs to be specified all lower case as

```
--feature string_escapes
```

*4 -Unless no target is specified (`-t none`).